# NestJS + CASL + Mongoose: CASL cannot infer subject type from Mongoose Schema

Tags: mongoose, authorization, nestjs, casl

### Context

I have defined a `Cat` schema using Mongoose and NestJS:

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type CatDocument = Cat & Document;

@Schema()
export class Cat {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  breed: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  createdBy: string;

  // Other fields...
}

export const CatSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cat);
```

I have also defined an ability factory using CASL to handle authorization for my API:

```js
import {
  Ability,
  AbilityBuilder,
  AbilityClass,
  ExtractSubjectType,
  InferSubjects,
} from '@casl/ability';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cat } from '../cats/schemas/cat.schema';
import { User } from '../users/models/user.model';

type Subjects = InferSubjects<typeof Cat | typeof User> | 'all';

export enum Action {
  Manage = 'manage',
  Create = 'create',
  Read = 'read',
  Update = 'update',
  Delete = 'delete',
}

export type AppAbility = Ability<[Action, Subjects]>;

@Injectable()
export class CaslAbilityFactory {
  createForUser(user: User) {
    const { can, build } = new AbilityBuilder<
      Ability<[Action, Subjects]>
    >(Ability as AbilityClass<AppAbility>);

    can(Action.Read, Cat);
    can(Action.Create, Cat);
    can(Action.Update, Cat, {
      createdBy: user.id,
    });

    if (user.isAdmin()) {
      can(Action.Manage, 'all');
    }

    return build({
      detectSubjectType: (item) =>
        item.constructor as ExtractSubjectType<Subjects>,
    });
  }
}
```

### Problem

When I try to check permissions in my service (note: the user is not an administrator):

```js
import {
  ForbiddenException,
  Injectable,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { EditCatInput } from './dto/edit-cat.input';
import { Cat, CatDocument } from './schemas/cat.schema';
import { Action, CaslAbilityFactory } from '../casl/casl-ability.factory';
import { User } from '../users/models/user.model';

@Injectable()
export class CatsService {
  constructor(
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    private readonly caslAbilityFactory: CaslAbilityFactory,
    @InjectModel(Cat.name) private catModel: Model<CatDocument>,
  ) {}

  // Other methods...

  async update(id: string, input: EditCatInput, user: User): Promise<Cat> {
    const updatedCat = await this.catModel
      .findOne({
        _id: { $eq: id },
        deleted: { $eq: false },
      })
      .exec();
    const ability = this.caslAbilityFactory.createForUser(user);
    if (!ability.can(Action.Update, updatedCat)) {
      throw new ForbiddenException(
        'You cannot edit this cat.',
      );
    }
    Object.assign(updatedCat, input);
    await updatedCat.save();

    return updatedCat;
  }
}
```

`ability.can(Action.Update, cat)` always return `false`, while it should be `true`.

### Additional information

`ability.can` returns `false` for any action when the user is not administrator.

My guess is that CASL cannot infer the subject type of my Mongoose model using the `Cat` class in `InferSubject` interface of the ability builder. But I don't know which class to use to infer subject type correctly.

What did I miss?

Comment: I've migrated to TypeORM since the publication of this question, and now ability works correctly.

Comment: has anyone sloution for this?

Answer (score 1):

So the key is to inject the cat model over nest js injection in the casl ability factory.
So a factory like this should work:

```js
import {
    Ability,
    AbilityBuilder,
    AbilityClass,
    ExtractSubjectType,
    InferSubjects,
  } from '@casl/ability';
  import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
  import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
  import { Model } from 'mongoose';
  import { Cat, CatDocument } from '../cats/schemas/cat.schema';
  import { User } from '../users/models/user.model';
  
  export enum Action {
    Manage = 'manage',
    Create = 'create',
    Read = 'read',
    Update = 'update',
    Delete = 'delete',
  }
  
  @Injectable()
  export class CaslAbilityFactory {
    constructor(
        @InjectModel(Cat.name)
        private catModel: Model<CatDocument>,
    ) {}
    createForUser(user: User) {
      const { can, build } = new AbilityBuilder(
        Ability as AbilityClass<
          Ability<[Action, InferSubjects<typeof this.catModel> | 'all']>
        >,
      );
  
      can(Action.Read, this.catModel);
      can(Action.Create, this.catModel);
      can(Action.Update, this.catModel, {
        createdBy: user.id,
      });
  
      if (user.isAdmin()) {
        can(Action.Manage, 'all');
      }
  
      return build({
        detectSubjectType: (item) =>
          item.constructor as ExtractSubjectType<InferSubjects<typeof this.catModel> | 'all'>,
      });
    }
  }
```

full example project:
https://github.com/Wenish/nestjs-mongoose-casl

Comment: Thanks, it solved for me also by importing "MongooseModule.forFeature..." in casl module [imports], but I was wondering if there's a cleaner way: following docs I've read that you can export MongooseModule in catModule for istance, but catModule needs to import caslModule (for checking permission in catService) and caslModule would need catsModule for the catModel (exported in MongoosModule), resulting in a circular dependecy. How did you solve it?

Comment: @ro.nin i have a databaseModule which registeres and exposes all the schemas.

so CaslModule and CatModule depend on DatabaseModule

Comment: I have the same problem @Johnny but your solution doesn't compile. Does this code still work for you? I am using all the latest versions. specifically the line `typeof this.catModel` fails because "Expression statement is not assignment or call"

Comment: @YossiShasho well i dont run any cat models in my code :P
so no i dont use this code myself.

but i think i copied this code from my example code from github:
https://github.com/Wenish/nestjs-mongoose-casl/blob/main/src/casl/casl-ability.factory.ts

for fun i re-run the build and yes it compiles as it did 4 months ago:
https://github.com/Wenish/nestjs-mongoose-casl/runs/7155827979?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: Thanks for checking @Johnny. I tried for quite some time to get this to work and failed. I'm using the latest versions of every package, so it could be that something changed since your versions. Anyway, in the meantime I decided to ditch Mongoose in favor of TypeORM, which worked, but not out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is ugly but it's the best I've found that doesn't involve migrating away from Mongoose.

The origin of the issue is that **mongoDB queries like findOne return Documents**, which are plain javascript objects typed as the union of `Cat & Document`. In your schema file if you've followed the default instructions you'll have something like `export type CatDocument = Cat & Document` where Cat is your schema and CatDocument is just a generated type for the benefit of Typescript.

However, Casl wants a class to validate against so trying to use the document will cause something like `'CatDocument' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

My solution is not pretty but it is simple and works, when you get a CatDocument **pass it to a function that turns it into a class**, since your schema doesn't have a constructor, you have to do something like this:

```js
  catDocToSchema(catDoc: CatDocument): Cat {
    const cat = new Cat();
    const forbidden = ['__v', '_id']; // Removes the __v and _id properties created by mongoose/mongodb
    for (const prop in catDoc) {
      if (!forbidden.includes(prop)) {
        cat[prop] = catDoc[prop];
      }
    }
    return cat;
  }
```

And run it before passing the object to your 'can' function:

```js
   userAbility.can(
     'Action',
     this.catService.catDocToSchema(catDoc),
   )
```

In the other proposed solution this.catModel compiles but doesn't actually validate as mentioned in the comments.
I also tried solutions that involved using js-mixer to create a class with multiple inheritance between Cat and Document. However, using contractors was near impossible and still required some transformation anyway.

I hope we find a better solution to this someday!

Answer (score 0):

InferSubject is not good fit for your solution try to use Subject helper method in docs https://casl.js.org/v4/en/guide/subject-type-detection